# how can I initialize 2D array of huge size 1000000x1000000?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, memory-management, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a cpp project in ubuntu with g++ compiler and I need to create a matrix of size 1000000x1000000 = 10^12 elements whose entries are boolean variables. But my g++ compiler is allowing me to allocate space to only around 1000x1000 elements. How can I overcome this problem of allocating space to this huge matrix?

Comment: You do not need a matrix that size. Lets assumes that it requires one second to process each entry (and you have enough memory!) then it will take 31 thousand of years! So I suspect this is a wind up

Comment: Maybe you could take one step back and explain how you arrived at the conclusion that you need this sized array.

Comment: Ok. Let say the size of matrix is mxn. We need to store a boolean value for each unique keyword-file(mxn) pair where maximum number of keywords(m) is around 10^6 and max number of files(n) in our database is assumed at 10^6.

Comment: If this is a homework, its purpose is probably to make you think of alternative techniques (sparse arrays, trees, hashtables, ....)

Answer (score 6):

You can't, unless you have at least 125GB of RAM (and that's assuming you need only one bit per `bool`). If you really need structures that large, you need to buy lots of RAM or think about on-disk algorithms.

But chances are that solving your problem does not actually require a 10^6 x 10^6 array, so you should rethink your algorithm first.

There are libraries that allow on-disk data structures (http://roomy.sourceforge.net/ comes to mind, and another one whose name I can't recall at the moment), but disk accesses are orders of magnitude slower than RAM. Unless you have thought this through very thoroughly, you will probably not be happy with the performance of a disk-based solution.

Comment: is there any other alternative to achieve this? using external storage like using file concept or using database?

Comment: i know it's a weird question but tried my luck if there could be any alternative like setting flags while compiling or resetting stack sizes which I read from other posts. The algorithm is designed so (data-mining project) and this matrix needs to store boolean values for 10^6x10^6 entries in the server actually but wanted to test the limits of it on my local machine. Anyways thanks for the info and library ref.

Comment: 1) It makes no difference if you initialize at compile time or runtime.  It requires memory in either case.  2) You don't need to "test the limits".  A pencil and paper is enough to do a calculation that will tell you how much memory is needed.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

**if majority of of the values are zero (false) try considering sparse matrix**. This will save space. Normally you can not create so large array.

---

**Here `vector<bool>::max_size()` will be the correct limit. But actually the standard does not guarantee that this allocation is possible.**

Note:my msvc compiler is showing the total array size should not exceed `0x7fffffff`.

Comment: in a 32bit build the limit is indeed 0x7fffffff.  I'm not sure 64 bit has the same limit

Comment: I've compiled the same with with setting x64 target in (vs2012). It's also showing the same upper limit. @MooingDuck

Comment: It shouldn't be, and the MSVC docs say otherwise: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b2e7499.aspx .  How are you checking this?

Comment: configuration manager->active solution platform: setting x64 here

Comment: I checked, when MSVC2012 is set to x64, `vector.at(` takes a `unsigned __int64`.  But you're right, that I can't allocate more than 0x7FFFFFF even when targetting x64.  Apperently this is a bug in the 32 bit version of MSVC2012: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/553756/invalid-check-for-maximum-array-size-in-x64-compiler-c2148.  An amusing workaround is to use `std::vector`

Comment: The question is tagged `linux` and `gcc`, so any restrictions MSVC may or may not impose are irrelevant.

Comment: The relevant portable figure would be `std::vector<T>::max_size()`

Comment: it gives me the following number on my machine - max_size: 4611686018427387903. No matter the given number if it is in bits or bytes, it might solve my problem i guess. But is it true? How can it handle this large memory without the actual physical memory being existed on the machine?

Comment: for this reason the standard doesn't guarantee that this allocation is possible

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- You are on a 64-bit system, as a 32-bit system doesn't have enough virtual address space to hold such a large array
- You have enough physical ram and disk swap space to hold the array

Then you will need to use a dynamically allocated array.  Generally the linker/loader has fixed limits on what it can handle in terms of statically allocated variables.

Try:

```
static_assert(sizeof(size_t) == 8, "64-bit required");

constexpr size_t N = 1000000;

vector<bool> V(N*N);

inline decltype(V[0]) get(size_t x, size_t y) { return V[x*N + y]; }
```

Unless you have in the order of 100GB of physical memory - keep in mind a random bit access will cause an entire page to be swapped to disk, which takes in the order of milliseconds.

Comment: Yes I'm on a 64-bit system but with 3.6GB RAM only. can u please tell me what do you mean by disk swap space?

Comment: by "dynamically allocated array", u mean as we initialize elements? in that case i would have to initialize all my entries in the matrix to zeroes initially. does vector works in this case? accessing the bits is not a big issue as it is not a frequent operation in the algorithm but storing them is critical and even time in order of millisec is acceptable.

Comment: @annunarcist: You're missing some basic knowledge of operating systems.  Read up on [Virtual Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and [Dynamic Memory Allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

Comment: from this i understood that u r trying to say that physical ram/memory means primary storage (physical RAM-3.6GB on my system) and space for disk swap is used from secondary storage(disk) which implies visualization allows a process to have memory more than the actual physical memory by allocating space from secondary storage(disk). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: and from the literature homework i have done, is it that every element of vector<bool> only uses one bit of memory to store?